# How to set a form for nested attributes with collection selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes, collection-select

I am trying to configure a form for nested attributes with a selector on RoR, but it seems I am doing it wrong.

I am trying to create a new `affaire` with nested_attributes `contributions`.
Each `contribution` belongs to a `skill` which needs to be defined.

As there is a limited number of possible `skills`, I would like to have a selector in my form to select the `contribution_skill` from a list.

EDIT : I finally made it save the affaire with contributions by setting all the `contribution` attributes (I used the defaut set in the model definition).
But I don't always want these attributes to be defined, so it is still not the solution.
I add that there is no presence validation on these attributes.
Anyone knows how to save a `nested_attribute` without all `nested_attribute_attributes` defined ?

Here is the models definitions :

```rb
class Affaire < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contributions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contributions
end


class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contributions
end

class Contribution < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :affaire
end
```

Controller definition :

```rb
def new
    @affaire = Affaire.new
    2.times {@affaire.contributions.build}
end

def create
    @affaire = Affaire.new(affaire_params)
    @affaire.save
    redirect_to @affaire
end

private
    def affaire_params
      params.require(:affaire).
        permit(:nam, contributions_attributes: [:id, :skill_id])
    end
```

View definition :

```rb
<%= form_with model: @affaire do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name, "Name of Affaire" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>

    <%= form.fields_for :contributions do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :skill_id, "Contribution" %>
        <%= ff.collection_select(:skill_id, Skill.all, :id, :name) %>
    <% end %>

<%= form.submit "Create affaire" %>
```

I am expecting to get my `affaire` created with my `contribution` and the `contribution` to have its `skill` set.
Unfortunately, it goes wrong.

Here iswhat I got in the `rails server` console :

```
Started GET "/affaires/new" for ::1 at 2019-09-04 21:06:41 +0200
Processing by AffairesController#new as HTML
  Rendering affaires/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Skill Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills"
  ↳ app/views/affaires/new.html.erb:30
  CACHE Skill Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills"
  ↳ app/views/affaires/new.html.erb:30
  Rendered affaires/new.html.erb within layouts/application (20.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 70.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)


Started POST "/affaires" for ::1 at 2019-09-04 21:06:48 +0200
Processing by AffairesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GCc2wX2C7mWn77eksjdhDp5i1lFoUc2L3MLkOIXmWhavNdxwIynpNTVaRmbrvkKNdRtQxqoXjaInI2MaJtvvFA==", "affaire"=>{"name"=>"test",  "contributions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"skill_id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"skill_id"=>"1"}}}} (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/affaires_controller.rb:20
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "skills".* FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/affaires_controller.rb:20
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "skills".* FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/affaires_controller.rb:20
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/affaires_controller.rb:20
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/affaires
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

I can't see where is the problem.
Parameters seems ok to me if I refer to rails documentation. I don't get why it rolls back.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your log file should have a lot more detail on the error. Can you post it please so we can see what the actual error being raised is. There is normally areason for the rollback given

Comment: I put some more details of the log from my /log/development.log file, but I don't see more details for the rollback.
Should I look somewhere else ?
(sorry I start with rails, I don't know a lot yet)

Comment: That's a bit better. It'll do ;)

Comment: Ok, that is even stranger that I thought.
The problem comes from the completion of all the `contributions` attributes (that I removed above in the post for clarity).
If I don't set all the `contribution` attributes, it does work, even if there is no presence validation on them in the `contribution` model !

Comment: It may be the order of things! Possibly the skill and or the affaire records do not exist yet when trying to save the contribution. Worth looking into